# Is it justified to use a one-tailed t-test if I my hypothesis is one-sided?

Tags: statistical-significance, t-test

I am looking to see if the mean of group A is higher than the mean of group B using an unpaired t-test. I don't really care if group B is lower than group A (it might actually mean something, but it isn't very useful). Given that my hypothesis is looking for an effect in one direction, is it justifiable to use a one-tailed t-test? If I clearly state my hypothesis in such a way that I am looking for an effect in a single direction, do I need to explicitly state that the p-value is one-tailed?

Comment: One question you might want to answer in the body of your question is what you would do if the test happened to be significant and in the opposite direction?

Comment: Yes. Acceptance of use of one-tailed tests varies (some application areas tend to be a bit prejudiced against them, probably because of past experience of significance-hunting by people deciding to use a one-tailed test *post hoc*), but if your justification is one that will seem obvious (that is, that a reader would understand would quite naturally be one-sided) there should be no problem at all.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, if you are only talking about the probability that $\mu_A > \mu_B$ then one would expect you to be using a one-tailed t-test and p-value.

More formally, your null hypothesis is $\text{H}_{0}: \mu_A \leq \mu_B$ and your alternative hypothesis, $\text{H}_{1}: \mu_A > \mu_B$, is one-sided.

(Granted, to avoid confusion I would clarify and reiterate the fact that the p-value is single-tailed wherever possible.)